# A Professional User Interface for Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, webgl

I need a user interface for my application in JavaScript. I need to be able to toggle all layers and also click on each object to zoom to that object.

I saw the following example and I need this or something similar to this.

[image]

https://human.biodigital.com/index.html

However, I could not extract the code form the application. Could you please help me to have the code if it is free for use. Otherwise, could you please give me a link to a similar user interface.

Thanks.

Comment: use something like [this](http://www.bootstrap-switch.org/examples.html) and try to implement your own logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho the best way to achieve this is use mediator pattern.

As a good source I can provide [this book](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#mediatorpatternjavascript).

> If it appears a system has too many direct relationships between components, ...

You want to have 2 components, engine that visualize everything and some panel as user interface. Panel is easy part, it is just long list of stuff and a lot of people here can help you to implement it. Mediator is a little bit harder but not that hard + I gave you source with precise description. First try to understand how does it work. I guess 50 lines of code long. Last thing you will need to do is to put listeners in your engine. This will be supereasy if you know how the visualization work (you are the author) or superhard if you dont know anything.

Extraction is not possible (way I just describe is easier then extraction) and the code is not free for use. And even if you could do it, you would still need to do job with adding listeners which I see as the most important.

If you want to advice with source code, you have to bring some examples first.